# Why ZeroMQ poll throws an error: "socket operation on non-socket"?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I encounter a serious and odd issue with ZeroMQ and its C++ binding: each time I perform a polling operation on zmq socket, it throws an error of:

> `socket operation on non-socket`

Below is the code to reproduce it:

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
int main() {

  zmq::context_t       ctx(1);
  zmq::socket_t sock1( ctx, ZMQ_REQ );
  zmq::socket_t sock2( ctx, ZMQ_PUB );

  sock1.bind( "tcp://*:10001" );
  sock2.bind( "tcp://*:10002" );

  zmq::pollitem_t* items = ( zmq::pollitem_t* ) malloc( 2 * sizeof( zmq::pollitem_t ) );

  items[0] = { &sock1, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 };
  items[1] = { &sock2, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 };

  while(1) {
    zmq::poll ( items, 2, 500 );  // Throws error !! socket operation on non-socket.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given ZeroMQ API / C++ binding documentation recommends to do so, one ought follow a practice to:

> To obtain a ØMQ socket for use in a **`zmq_pollitem_t`** structure, you should cast an instance of the **`socket_t`** class to **`(void *)`**.

Comment: I've always thought that this is a nasty little thing in the C++ bindings. It relies on the first member variable in the zmq::socket_t class being the C zmq socket. If you edit the definition of zmq::socket_t to change the member variable order it breaks stuff, badly.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for user3666197's answer. Although cast an object to a void* pointer making me feel weired [zmq reference with an example](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-poll)

Comment: Instead of C-style casting you can use socket_t::operator void*() explicitly